# Как поменять заливку SVG по нажатию на button

Tags: javascript, html, json, svg, button

Написал маленький скрипт чтоб по нажатию на BUTTON менялась заливка насоса в формате SVG но почему-то не работает (( Что не так ?

КОД HTML:

```
<a><button type="button" class="pum" value="Насос1" onClick="doIt(1)">Насос1</button></a>
```

КОД JS:

```
var path1216Click=document.getElementById("path1216");   
function doIt(1) {
    if (path1216.style.fill == "#0aff00") {
        path1216.style.fill = "#ff0000";
    }
    else {
        path1216.style.fill = "#1400ff";
    }
}
```

КОД SVG. id="path1216":

```
<g
    id="pump-1"
    inkscape:label="#g1267"
    transform="matrix(0.81036317,0,0,0.81036317,51.74355,-26.659243)">
        <circle
           r="14.303132"
           cy="225.50253"
           cx="-28.786152"
           id="path1216"
           style="fill:#0aff00;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2.4000001;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" />
```

Comment: `function doIt(1)` - имя переменной (в данном случае, переменной-аргумента) не может быть числом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var counter = 1;
var path1216Click = document.getElementById("path1216");

var doIt = function() {
  if (counter == 1) {
    path1216.style.fill = "#ff0000";
    counter++;
  } else if (counter == 2) {
    path1216.style.fill = "#1400ff";
    counter++;
  } else if (counter == 3) {
    path1216.style.fill = "#0aff00";
    counter = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<a><button type="button" class="pum" value="Насос1" onClick="doIt()">Насос1</button></a>
<svg width="300" heigth="300" viewBox="0 0 180 180">
<g
    id="pump-1"
    inkscape:label="#g1267"
    transform="matrix(0.81036317,0,0,0.81036317,51.74355,-26.659243)">
        <circle
           r="14.303132"
           cy="225.50253"
           cx="-28.786152"
           id="path1216"
           style="fill:#0aff00;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2.4000001;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" />
           </g></svg>
```

Comment: А чтоб можно было 3 раза нажать .То есть по первому нажатию например синий, второе нажатие-красный ,третье-зеленый и на исходную.

Comment: Поправил, правда с цветами, вроде бы напутал, но это легко поправить

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное ,вы меня сильно выручили!!!!

Comment: Добрый день Сергей . А можете пожалуйста глянуть эту тему ? "Выводить рандомные значения в графиках"